# How to merge two tables for a query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table animal:

```
CREATE TABLE animal
(
    id_animal serial primary key,
    id_parent INT,
    lft INT NOT NULL,
    rgt INT NOT NULL

);
```

And table animal_lang:

```
CREATE TABLE animal_lang
(
        id_animal_lang serial  primary key,
        id_animal int  constraint animal_lang_ibfk_1 references animal on delete cascade,
        code varchar(5) not null,
        name varchar(100) not null,
        descri varchar(255) not null
);
```

From table animal i get data using query:

```
SELECT animal.*, (COUNT(parent.id_animal) - 1) AS depth 
FROM animal AS animal, animal AS parent 
WHERE (animal.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt) 
GROUP BY animal.id_animal;
```

How to get this data additionally with 'name' and 'descri' from table animal_lang for specifed 'code'?

with

```
WHERE  animal_lang.code = 'eng'
```

result should looks:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/puoLK.png]

I am using [Nested Tree Model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

sample data for animals:

```
INSERT INTO animal VALUES (43, 1, 2, 5);
INSERT INTO animal VALUES (46, 44, 7, 8);
INSERT INTO animal VALUES (47, 43, 3, 4);
INSERT INTO animal VALUES (1, NULL, 1, 14);
INSERT INTO animal VALUES (44, 1, 6, 11);
INSERT INTO animal VALUES (45, 1, 12, 13);
INSERT INTO animal VALUES (48, 44, 9, 10);
```

sample data for animal_lang

```
INSERT INTO animal_lang VALUES (1, 43, 'eng', 'EnglishTitleXXX', 'EnglishDXXX');
INSERT INTO animal_lang VALUES (2, 45, 'eng', 'EnglishTitleYYY', 'EnglishDYYY');
INSERT INTO animal_lang VALUES (3, 44, 'eng', 'EnglishTitleZZZ', 'EnglishDZZZ');
INSERT INTO animal_lang VALUES (4, 1, 'eng', 'EnglishTitleUUU', 'EnglishDUUU');
INSERT INTO animal_lang VALUES (5, 46, 'eng', 'EnglishTitleQQQ', 'EnglishDQQQ');
INSERT INTO animal_lang VALUES (6, 47, 'eng', 'EnglishTitleDDD', 'EnglishDDDD');
INSERT INTO animal_lang VALUES (7, 48, 'eng', 'EnglishTitleHHH', 'EnglishDHHH');
INSERT INTO animal_lang VALUES (8, 43, 'ger', 'GermanTitleXXX', 'GermanDXXX');
INSERT INTO animal_lang VALUES (9, 45, 'ger', 'GermanTitleYYY', 'GermanDYYY');
INSERT INTO animal_lang VALUES (10, 44, 'ger', 'GermanTitleZZZ', 'GermanDZZZ');
INSERT INTO animal_lang VALUES (11, 1, 'ger', 'GermanTitleUUU', 'GermanDUUU');
INSERT INTO animal_lang VALUES (12, 46, 'ger', 'GermanTitleQQQ', 'GermanDQQQ');
INSERT INTO animal_lang VALUES (13, 47, 'ger', 'GermanTitleDDD', 'GermanDDDD');
INSERT INTO animal_lang VALUES (14, 48, 'ger', 'GermanTitleHHH', 'GermanDHHH');
```

I tried to do this like that:

```
SELECT animal.*, trans.*, (COUNT(parent.id_animal) - 1) AS depth
FROM animal AS animal, animal AS parent
LEFT JOIN animal_trans as trans on animal.id_animal = trans.id_animal
WHERE (animal.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt)
GROUP BY animal.id_animal;
```

but this error occurs:

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "animal"
LINE 3: LEFT JOIN animal_trans as trans on animal.id_animal = ...
                                             ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "animal", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  This clarifies the question and is particularly important (in my opinion) for hierarchical data structures.

Comment: I added sample row output and I eddited a little question. Tell me if u need anything else.

Comment: @Verh - What Gordon trying to mean is add sample data for both the tables `animal` and `animal_lang` and proper expected output

Comment: Your create table DDL for `animal_lang` is wrong, `id_animal_lang` appears twice, also `INSERT INTO animal VALUES (1, NULL, 1, 14);` is not applicable for the `animal` table since lft and rgt fields are `NOT NULL`. Please try building your schema first on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: @fozzy Yea, edited, it should be `id_animal` (forgein key from `animal` table), null is for id_parent and it can be null (first element havnt parent)

Comment: You need to edit, like foozy said: INSERT INTO animal VALUES (1, NULL, 1, 14); is not applicable for the animal table since lft and rgt fields are NOT NULL.

Comment: what are you triying to do with (COUNT(parent.id_animal) - 1) as depth? always show 6... .

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla damn, i put `id_parent INT` in wrong place, edited, sorry. Its id_animal, id_parent, lft and rgt

Comment: you need to erase the last column in the animal table, you can have two identical name column... id_parent.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla no idea how it happen, edited, sorry again.

Comment: Its ok dude, but i cant get what are you triying to do... . check my answer and then we will try to edited for you need, what is the criteria to depth column in the query, in your query (COUNT(parent.id_animal) - 1) AS depth always return 6... .

Comment: and what is animal trans... . Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69558/discussion-between-juan-ruiz-de-castilla-and-verh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
A.id_animal,A.id_parent,A.lft,A.rgt,
(SELECT count(*) 
FROM animal A2 
WHERE A.lft BETWEEN A2.lft AND A2.rgt)-1
as depth, 
B.name, 
B.descri
FROM animal A, animal_lang B
WHERE A.id_animal = B.id_animal
AND B.code = 'eng'
```

It look like your "result should look" example.

Comment: but depth is wrong, there is no empty string in depth

Comment: go to chat dude... to explain me better what are you triying... . in the other comment is the link,... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69558/discussion-between-juan-ruiz-de-castilla-and-verh

Comment: well i will waiting for you 5 more minutes... .

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE (animal.lft BETWEEN animal.lft AND animal.rgt)
```

Assuming that `animal.rgt >= animal.lft`, this clause will *always* be true.  You almost certainly want something else before the `BETWEEN`.